# textslide in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope I can get some advice on how to make this function. I have a form where the function should be that, when a person click inside the form, the text should slide up on the top-border of the form.

While the text is sliding up, the top-border should make space for the text. I made an illustration of it here:

[image: Textslide in form]

I am quite insecure how I can do that. I know I need to use JQuery. So I tried to start making a prototype on it, but I do not know where to go. I hope there is someone how can guide me in the right direction?

```
<form action="/getdata.php">
  <input type="text" value="Firstname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



$('form').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
    $('div').animate({marginLeft:"0"},1500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="inputContainer">
   <input type="text">
   <label>FirstName</label>
</div>
```

Now first lets make the label on top of the input

```
.inputContainer {
    position: relative;
}

inputContainer label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 20px; (relative to your input)
}
```

now you can manipulate the label and with jQuery the recommended way is the focus event, and then just change the left and top prop of the label.